# Display image in full screen on clicking it

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am working on an instant chat application .I have 3 tabs in an Activity namely Chat,Group and Contact.In Group Tab ,i have a list view which is populated using BaseAdapter.Now list view can contain images .On clicking image ,i want to display it in full screen.

Inside adpater i am using following code on clicking imageview :

```
//On clicking image,display the image in full screen


 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", image);
                context.startActivity(intent);              
            }
        });
```

Here "image" is the base 64 representation of an image .

**FullImageActivity.java**

```
    public class FullImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imgFullImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

        ///findViewBYID
        imgFullImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String image = bundle.getString("image");
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeImage(image);
        imgFullImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }    

    private Bitmap decodeImage(String data) {
        byte[] b = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

But it is not working for me .When i click on it moves to FullIMageActivity and instantly move back to Group Tab.Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Passing an image as a part of intent may not be such a great idea :) Why dont you save the image somewhere in your internal or external storage and provide the path to next activity in intent ?

Comment: hey Deepak Are you making with XMPP and Asmack lib..???

Comment: @NikhilBorad : I am using socket.io-client library in my app.

Comment: @NikhilBorad: Yeah Sure.

Comment: come to this... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/110529/chat-app-android?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, this is how you can do it

In your first Activity

Convert `ImageView` to Bitmap First

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and in second Activity

```
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Then display bitmap in your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

Here `Base64` image is big string of data that can be intent with pass to other activity is bad idea, because that in you can loss data or application get more load. that for use to make one model class that in store `Base64` string and retrieve it. **How? see below code**.

**ModelBase64.java**

```
class ModelBase64{
   public static String base64Image;
}
```

now assign image string to `base64Image`

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ModelBase64.base64Image=image;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullImageActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);              
        }
    });
```

Now retrive in another class

**FullImageActivity.java**

```
public class FullImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imgFullImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

    ///findViewBYID
    imgFullImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);

   // Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //String image = bundle.getString("image");
    String image = ModelBase64.base64Image;
    Bitmap bitmap = decodeImage(image);
    imgFullImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}    

private Bitmap decodeImage(String data) {
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    return bmp;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply for you best fit solution is ImageViewPopUpHelper.
https://github.com/juliomarcos/ImageViewPopUpHelper

get source from this url and make a Class name "ImageViewPopUpHelper". after that whenever you want to see pop up on click, define setOnClicklistner on that image like

```
profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ 
   @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
       ImageViewPopUpHelper.enablePopUpOnClick(activity, profile_image, profile_image.getDrawable());
   }
});
```

Comment: you should post some of part code and explain something. and you can post link in comment that is not proper way

Comment: get source from this url and make a Class name "ImageViewPopUpHelper". after that whenever you want to see pop up on click, define setOnClicklistner on that image like                               profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ImageViewPopUpHelper.enablePopUpOnClick(activity, profile_image, profile_image.getDrawable());
                        }
                    });

Comment: got it but you have to update your answer and put this comment in in your post.